# How to multiply two sublists within the same list?

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and SO. I want to multiply each element of lists in a list of lists to another list lying in the same list of lists and compare it with a reference value. This will be more clear with an example:

```
for L = [[1,2,3,4,5,10],[3,2,4,1,5,10]] ##there can be more than 2 lists in this list of lists
```

I want only those pairs whose product results in 10.

```
Out: L = [[1,10],[2,5]]
```

*Edit: I prefer a method without any imports*, since I am doing this for building logic and my editor doesn't contain any modules to import. Also, if there are more than 2 lists in a list of lists For eg. there are 3 Lists in a list of lists: then I want triplets for that sake. ANd if 4 lists then I need quadruples.

Here's my code attempt as requested.

```
N = []
J = []
F = []
Z = []
S = []
O = []
num = input("Enter no. of elements in list")
print ('Enter numbers')
prod = 1
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = input("num :")
    N.append(int(n))
for x in N:
    prod = prod*x
print (prod)
k = int(input("Enter no. of splits:"))
##d = [[] for x in xrange(k)]
##var_dict = [] 
for o in range(1,prod+1):
    if prod%o == 0:
        J.append(o)
print (J)
for g in range(k): 
  O.append(J*(k-1))
print (O)
for a in range(len(O)):
    for b in range(len(O)):
        if O[i]*O[i+1] == prod:
            Z.extend(O)

##Z = [[a, b] for a in J for b in F if a*b == prod] ##imp
print (Z)
for e in Z:
    if e not in S and sorted(e) not in S:
        S.append(e)
print (S)
```

Comment: Where is the 10 coming from? What about the pair `[5, 2]`?

Comment: @RitikSamaiya In your output you have the pair `[1, 10]`. How is that coming from your input? Also, what about the 5 in sublist 1 and the 2 in sublist 2?

Comment: pardon me @miradulo I just edited the correct input for corresponding output I am really sorry for the erroneous explanation. Also, I really don't want repeating contents like [5,2] and [2,5] but If the duplicates appear i will rectify them.

Comment: @RoryDaulton : If there are more than 2 lists in a list of lists For eg. there are 3 Lists in a list of lists: then I want triplets for that sake. ANd if 4 lists then I need quadruples.

Comment: I edited in your desire for code without imports, as you state in a comment to an answer, as well as your comment that there may be more than two sublists in your overall list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say you say you want code without any imports. Importing `product` from itertools and `reduce` do simplify and speed the code, but the job can be done without imports. Here is a recursive solution. I am not quite satisfied with this code but it seems to work and passes all my tests. I generalized the problem somewhat so that the input can have tuples or other sequences and not just lists.

```
def prod_is_target(seq_of_seqs, target):
    """Return a list of lists, where each sublist contains one member
    of each input subsequence in order, and the product of those
    members equals the target value. If there is no such list possible,
    return None. If seq_of_seqs is empty, return an empty list if the
    target is 1 and return None otherwise.
    """
    if not seq_of_seqs:  # if is empty sequence
        return [] if target == 1 else None
    result = []
    for val in seq_of_seqs[0]:
        if target % val:  # skip if target is not a multiple of val
            continue
        prodlists = prod_is_target(seq_of_seqs[1:], target // val)
        if prodlists is None: # skip if failed with later sublists
            continue
        if not prodlists:  # if is empty list
            result.append([val])
        else:
            for prodlist in prodlists:
                result.append([val] + prodlist)
    return result if result else None

print(prod_is_target([[1,2,3,4,5,10], [3,2,4,1,5,10]], 10))
```

The printout from that code is

```
[[1, 10], [2, 5], [5, 2], [10, 1]]
```

I'll leave it to you to remove what you consider to be duplicates. I can think of situations where you would want this full list, however.

Comment: it was very nice of you, your code is way more optimized than mine. But the sole purpose to do hat was logic. I guess I learned a lot from your code but for now, I will just work over and improve my code.

Comment: @RitikSamaiya: The difficulty, and the reason for the recursion, is that the number of sublists in the main list is not set in advance. If you know there will be exactly two sublists, the code can be much simpler. There is a non-recursive solution for this problem but is is longer than the routine I gave. If you want code for that case, ask another question on this site and make that clear, but remember to include a link to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` to find groups of numbers and filter them based on their product

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,10],[3,2,4,1,5,10]]
>>> ans = [p for p in product(*lst) if reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, p) == 10]
>>> # Remove duplicates
>>> ans = list(map(list, set(map(frozenset, ans))))
>>> print (ans)
[[1, 10], [2, 5]]
>>>
```

Comment: Is there any other method where this can be achieved without importing the modules.

Comment: @RitikSamaiya Unless you have a very good reason for not using `itertools`, I guess it makes sense to import the module !

Comment: @RafaelC : you are correct. But I am doing this for building logic. And I am not quite there, also my editor doesn't contain any modules to import. These reasons adds up thus I am not willing to use `itertools`

Comment: @RitikSamaiya. You can replace `reduce` with something else to find the product of all numbers in a list/tuple. But it is very hard to do without `itertools.product` especially when you dont have fixed number of sub lists in your list

Comment: @Sunitha Your method converts my list of lists into a list of tuples. Due to which I am unable to proceed for following code only applicable for list of lists:
`S =[]
for e in ans:
    if e not in S and sorted(e) not in S:
        S.append(e)
print(S)`